# Detect if I'm building Executable or Dynamic Library?

Tags: c++

I have two versions of my app, one works as a dynamic library loaded from a host app and another one works as a standalone executable app.

In my code, there are parts where I need to use different code depending on which version I'm building.

Is there a way to detect if I'm building a dynamic library or a standalone executable app so I can use the same source files for the two versions?

I would appreciate a cross-platform solution.

---

ADDED:

**My dynamic lib or executable code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
#ifdef IS_DYNAMICLIB
    std::cout << "Compiled as a dynamic library!\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Compiled as an executable!\n";
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

**In the terminal on macOS and I build it using the command:**

```
g++ -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace main.cpp -o Test.dylib
```

Now, I have `Test.dylib`

**Host app code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void* handle;
    typedef void (*func_t)();

    handle = dlopen("/Path/to/Test.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {

        printf("failed to open the library\n");
        return 0;
    }
    func_t mainFunc = (func_t) dlsym(handle, "main");

    if (!mainFunc) {

        printf("failed to find main method\n");
        dlclose(handle);
        return 0;
    }
    mainFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run this, I get:

```
Compiled as an executable!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But I would like it to print:

```
Compiled as a dynamic library!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to know at compile time, link time, load time or runtime

Comment: @Yunnosch I want to know at compile time if possible.

Comment: Can you build differently in other ways? E.g. with something of a `-Dlibbuild=1` for lib and a `-Dlibbuild=0` otherwise?

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know what you mean. I use Xcode. Should I add the flag? and how can I detect it in code?

Comment: @XCode is but an IDE, unrelated to your compiler or code. He talks about compiler options. Provided you use clang or gcc, you can can add a preprocesssor directive with -D flag. For cross-platform solution it's a good idea to use CMake as a tool of generating  project files.

Comment: Please show in detail how you build your two versions. E.g. the commandline you use, or the make file, or please list all the configuration options you use in your IDE/GUI. Then I think I could make an answer showing you how to implement my proposal. Also please show a little complete program (built the same way) which prints "Building as...". I can use that to show how to then use it with identical code to print "lib" or "standalone" instead of "...".

Comment: @Yunnosch I added a simplest version of showing what I want to do. I hope you can help me now.

Comment: You have only shown one way of building. I think it is the one for building as lib. Please also show the building details for building the other way.

Comment: The host app looks like it already assumes that a lib is used. How would it look for the non-lib version?

Comment: Problem is, compile-time is before linkage-time: compile-time you cannot tell what linker-options you will use linkage-time. (Though if you compile without -fPIC (on platforms that have pic and non-pic code), the object cannot be linked into a shared-object.